# Do a Mesmerist's spells provoke attacks of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, opportunity-attack

If a spell contains no material or somatic components — e.g. telepathic casting (Mesmerist) — does it provoke attacks of opportunity?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't have anything to do with the components, just the casting time:

> Spells that require only a free action to cast don’t provoke attacks of opportunity. - *Pathfinder RPG*, p. 185

This is reinforced by an earlier passage on metamagic:

> Metamagic feats that eliminate components of a spell don't eliminate the attack of opportunity proved by casting a spell while threatened. - *Pathfinder RPG*, p. 113

Comment: Fluff-wise, I think it has more to do with the mental effort required to cast than the physical components.
Mechanics-wise, it is to keep spells from being even more over-powered by mixing combat and casting (unless you take the appropriate feats of course).